# Proof of a formula for the power set of a union of two sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I need to prove that:

$2^{A\cup B} =\left \{ X\cup Y \mid X\in 2^{A}, Y\in2^{B} \right \}$

Note that $2^{A} = P(A)$ (The power set of A).

While I can prove the Right - Left direction fairly easily, It seems very hard for me to prove the Left - Right direction. Can I get some help with that? 
How do I prove that $t\in2^{A\cup B}$ makes $t\in \left \{ X\cup Y \mid X\in 2^{A}, Y\in2^{B} \right \}$?

Comment: I appears one is not supposing $A$ and $B$ disjoint here; the result is true without that hypothesis, but a bit more care in formulation is needed. I suppose "left-right" means the inclusion "$\subseteq$". Also, it is not "power set", not "power group".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove $2^{(A \cup B)}=\left\{ X\cup Y| X\in 2^A, Y\in 2^B\right\}$ for sets $A,B$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3155618/prove-2a-cup-b-left-x-cup-y-x-in-2a-y-in-2b-right-for-sets-a-b)

Comment: Actually $2^A$ has a standard meaning - it's _not_ literally equal to the power set. Here it actually makes a differennce..

Answer (score 1):

If $t \in 2^{A\cup B}$, then $ t \subseteq A \cup B.$

Put $t_1:= t \cap A$ and $t_2:= t \cap B$. Then $t_1 \in 2^A, t_2 \in 2^B $ and $t=  t_1 \cup t_2 $. Thus

$$t\in \left \{ X\cup Y \mid X\in 2^{A}, Y\in2^{B} \right \}.$$

Comment: Note that $t=t_1\cup t_2$ again needs a proof showing both $\subseteq$ and $\supseteq$ (an easy one for sure).

Answer (score 1):

If $t\in2^{A\cup B}$ then every element of $t$ is in $A$ or in $B$, so in either $t\cap A$ or $t\cap B$. Thus $t=X\cup Y$ where $X=t\cap A\in2^A$ and $Y=t\cap B\in 2^B$.