# Prove $2^{(A \cup B)}=\left\{ X\cup Y| X\in 2^A, Y\in 2^B\right\}$ for sets $A,B$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Please help me prove $2^{A\cup B}=\left\{ X\cup Y| X\in 2^A, Y\in 2^B\right\}$

Comment: Should that be $X\cap Y$?

Comment: The statement is false as written; for example, take $A=\{1\}, B=\{2\}$; $\{1,2\}$ is in the right hand side set, but is not in $2^{A\cap B}$.  As the other commenters point out, there are two ways to fix the question.

Comment: Maybe $2^{A \cup B}$ ?

Comment: yes its just like @MauroALLEGRANZA siad  2A∪B Sorry again for the mistake
Edit also  X∪Y

Comment: I edited the question, figured out how to write the symbols, kinda

Comment: Was the problem stated in terms of $2^S$, as here, or in terms of power sets? Here it makes a big difference - the version you give here is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, suppose $E \in \mathcal{P}(A \cup B)$. Then, we can write 
$$E = E \cap (A \cup B) = (E \cap A) \cup (E \cap B) \in \{X \cup Y : X \in \mathcal{P}(A) \land Y \in \mathcal{P}(B) \}.$$

Now, take $E \in \{X \cup Y : X \in \mathcal{P}(A) \land Y \in \mathcal{P}(B) \}$. Then, $E = X \cup Y$, where $X \in \mathcal{P}(A)$ and $Y \in \mathcal{P}(B)$. Then, $E=X \cup Y \subset A \cup B \implies E \in \mathcal{P}(A \cup B)$.

In the above, $E$ is an arbitrary element of the given sets. What the above proves is 
$$\mathcal{P}(A \cup B) \subset \{X \cup Y : X \in \mathcal{P}(A) \land Y \in \mathcal{P}(B) \}$$
and
$$\{X \cup Y : X \in \mathcal{P}(A) \land Y \in \mathcal{P}(B) \} \subset \mathcal{P}(A \cup B).$$

Comment: are all the X's the same 
and the U and V instead of the X and Y in the original question?

Comment: The $X$'s are arbitrary. Let me edit it to align with your notation.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand\P{\mathcal{P}}$

Actually the claim is false as written! The accepted answer proves the corresponding result with $\P(S)$ in place of $2^S$. Yes, there's a natural equivalence between $\P(S)$ and $2^S$, but this equivalence does not commute with unions.

By definition  $2^S$ is the set of all functions mapping $S$ to $2=\{0,1\}$.
Suppose $a\in A\cap B$, $X\in 2^A$, $Y\in 2^B$, $X(a)=0$ and $Y(a)=1$. That is to say $(a,0)\in X$ and $(a,1)\in Y$; hence $X\cup Y$  is not even a function,  hence certainly not an element of $2^{A\cup  B}$.